# ng-repeat with different ng-click on first index

Tags: angularjs

I have a json array with 5 items.  I am using ng-repeat to display them.

I have this line inside the ng-repeat:

```
<li class="funct" ng-class="{'editContact' : $index > 0 }" data-ng-hide="editMode" data-ng-click="editMode = true; addEdit(contact)">
```

BUT for the very first row (index 0) I need it to be:

```
<li class="funct" ng-class="{ 'editContact' : $index > 0 }" data-ng-hide="editMode" data-ng-click="editMode = false; addEdit(contact)">
```

The difference is the data-ng-click  It's only in the first row I need it to be FALSE.  Iv'e tried a number of things but can't seem to get it.  Any ideas?  I'm kinda lost at this point.

Comment: Have you considered displaying the first row separately with the first item in the array and running ng-repeat with the array of the remaining four items?

Comment: This mean you want to able edit in each row except 0 index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check with [**ng-if**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf)

```
<li class="funct" ng-if="$index === 0"   data-ng-hide="editMode" data-ng-click="editMode = false; addEdit(contact)">
```

Comment: Hey there, I've tried that.  It's not quite "right".

Comment: @CS why do you say that?

Comment: It's leaving the first record exactly how I want it ... but it effects all the other records.  I need the other records to have ALL the same stuff but have "editMode = true".  - for example, it's stripping the ng-click anda few other ng parameters.

I just need a way for ng-click on the first record to be "editMode=false ; addEdit(contacts)"  and all the other records to be "editMode=true; addEdit(contacts)"

Comment: @CS You need to have another li with ng-if for other records

Comment: yeah.  But for a simple  TRUE/FALSE toggle ... it's not practical.  It means creating 3-4 li's for all the various permutations of what needs to happen.  so, 5 records x 3 or 4 means 15-20 li's.  I'll find another way.  Thank you tho.